# Распараллеливание нагрузки загрузки одного файла

Tags: linux, torrent

Есть два интернет соединения, по кабелю, и по Wifi. К примеру по кабелю раздаётся мобильный интернет со скоростью 40Мбит/c, а по Wifi 50Мбит/с, есть ли способ "распаралелить" загрузку  к примеру какой-нибудь игры с торрента?

Если есть VPS со скоростью интернет соединения 100Мбит/с, без большого хранилища, возможно ли через него

Comment: игры, линукса или торрента?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Торрент клиент, один из не многих инструментов, способный распараллелить загрузку, для этого нужно исследовать адреса "жирных" раздающих, и на шлюзе настроить firewall так, чтобы запросы одних раздающих, шли через один адаптер, других через другой, в зависимости от их адреса.
VPS в интернете, ни как не поможет в загрузке данных на локальный компьютер, здесь узкое место "последняя миля".

Comment: vps очень поможет. но сделать два линка довольно сложно